# MySQL cumulative sum with multiple group

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, cumulative-sum

I saw correlative posts about this problem but I cound't find the solution for my problem.

I'm trying to add a column with cumulative sum of another column but with multiple parameter for grouping.

This is my code for selecting the current information:

```
SELECT t.daytime,
DATE(t.daytime) AS day,
t.CODE,
SUM(t.QTD) AS QTD,
t.TMOV,
IF(t.TMOV = '-', SUM(t.QTD)*(-1), SUM(t.QTD)) AS MQTD
FROM t 
WHERE DATE(t.daytime) BETWEEN '2021-11-01' AND '2021-12-21'
GROUP BY DATE(t.daytime), t.CODE, t.TMOV
ORDER BY t.CODE, t.daytime;
```

Result table:

[image]

And finaly I'm trying to add the cumulative sum of 'MQTD' with group of day and CODE. Objective:

[image]

Sorry, i'm not a expert in mysql, I tried all different solutions but didn't get the desired result

Comment: Check MySQL version by running `SELECT version();`

Comment: By the way, I see you're doing aggregation but you didn't include `t.TMOV` in the `GROUP BY` despite being in `SELECT`. This is incompatible with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` setting; which I assume is disabled. But what if within the `GROUP BY DATE(t.daytime), t.CODE` grouping, one (or more) of the `t.TMOV` value is `-` while the others are `+`? Which one should you prioritise?

Comment: SELECT version (); = 5.5.34. About **t.TMOV** in **GROUP BY** it was a error when I copied the code here. I'll edit my queston adding t.TMOV in group by.

Comment: The t.TMOV sign is just used to created the t.MQTD column, and I'll use this column to get the cumulative sum.

Comment: There's no direct way to do this task in MySQL and it's quite hard to do in older versions, whereas on MySQL v8+ that support windows function, while it might still be indirect, it's probably a lot easier to do. I suggest you create a [db.fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=3bbebf7efe9f01901d41d4013bf96b4c) and insert your sample data there so that we can do some testing.

Comment: I have access to the source database through username and password and my access is restricted, only allowed to make select queries. And if I create a **new mysql database (v.8.0)** and use ```select``` queries to import data from the **source database** to this new database? But I don't have any idea how I could do that, do you have? Thanks for the help

Comment: If you're just going to install v8 locally for this task then you can setup the server first, create database. After that `mysqldump` the table that you want, then import into the new server. [Here's a reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html)

Comment: But I don't have access to the source database to use ```mysqldump```. I can only use ```select``` queries to access data from source database.

Comment: Do you have access to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`?

Comment: Yes, I can run **SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name**

Comment: Then you can use that to create table schema in your new database. For the data, you can modify your `SELECT` query with combination of `CONCAT()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` so that you can use it for `INSERT`. [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=b327995c0aa7acd7616858f330b4882e)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll try it.